# Reading a file then converting the string into a float and finding avg,sum,lowest,and highest totals

Tags: python-3.x

The issue that I am having is that when the program reads the file, it is reading the name as well as the numbers which is necessary, but I cant get the numbers to be converted to a float. The text file is called "gym.txt", and that is what I have to read from. I am in a low level coding class, so the code should be somewhat basic. The following are the contents of "gym.txt":

```
5
Albert 9.2 9.3 9.0 9.9 9.5 9.5 9.6 9.8
John 9.1 9.4 9.6 9.8 9.4 9.3 9.9 9.1
Jay 9.2 9.3 9.0 9.9 9.4 9.3 9.9 9.1
Henry 9.4 9.3 9.9 9.1 9.5 9.5 9.6 9.8
Walter 9.2 9.3 9.4 9.3 9.9 9.1 9.6 9.0
```

The 5 indicates the number of competitors, and of these scores, the highest and lowest for each person is dropped. The total of numbers then becomes 6 and it is excluding the lowest and highest scores for each person.

I have tried reading the file line by line as shown in the code below, and converting it to float is failing due to the names being in the same line as the numbers. I planned on doing this code for each name and set of scores if it worked.

```
f=open('gym.txt','r')
judges=6
contestants=f.readline().rstrip("\n")
print(contestants)
albert=str(f.readline().rstrip('\n'))
albert_list=float(albert.strip("Albert"))
print(albert_list)
```

The expected results is the following output:

```
The number of contestants is 5.

Contestant          Scores
_______________________________________________

Albert  9.3 9.0 9.9 9.5 9.5 9.6 9.8 

John    9.4 9.6 9.8 9.4 9.3 9.9 9.1 

Jay 9.3 9.0 9.9 9.4 9.3 9.9 9.1 

Henry   9.3 9.9 9.1 9.5 9.5 9.6 9.8 

Walter  9.3 9.4 9.3 9.9 9.1 9.6 9.0 
Total score of Albert is 9.48.
Total score of John is 9.43.
Total score of Jay is 9.37.
Total score of Henry is 9.52.
Total score of Walter is 9.32.
The highest total score amongst the contestants is 9.52.
The lowest total score amongst the contestants is 9.32.
```

Formatting is not a huge issue for me, I'm just interested in help with the program itsself. This is the error that I am getting:

```
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/theon/PycharmProjects/untitled/CS 1113/gymnasium.py", line 6, in <module>
    albert_list=float(albert.strip("Albert"))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 9.2 9.3 9.0 9.9 9.5 9.5 9.6 9.8'
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like this:**

```
with open('gym.txt', 'r') as file:
    all_file = file.read().strip()  # Read and remove any extra new line
    all_file_list = all_file.split('\n')  # make a list of lines
    number_of_contestant = all_file_list.pop(0)  # get the first line (removes form the all_file_list as well)
    data = []
    # Except for names, number will be converted to floats, Rejects the 1st max and min number too
    for line in all_file_list:
        line_list = line.split()
        temp_list = [x if i == 0 else float(x) for i, x in enumerate(line_list)]  # convert string float to Float
        temp_list.remove(max(temp_list[1:]))  # Remove the max
        temp_list.remove(min(temp_list[1:]))  # Remove the min
        data.append(temp_list)
    print('The number of contestants is {}.'.format(number_of_contestant))
    print('_' * 50)
    print('{} {:^50}'.format('Contestent', 'Scores'))
    print('_' * 50)
    for row in data:
        print('{:<15} {}'.format(row[0], '  '.join([str(x) for x in row[1:]])))
    print('_' * 50)
    print('_' * 50 + '\n')
    total_score = []
    for row in data:
        row_total_score = sum(row[1:]) / len(row[1:])
        total_score.append(row_total_score)
        print('{:<30} {:.2f}'.format('Total Score of ' + row[0] + ' is: ', row_total_score))
    print('_' * 50 + '\n' + '_' * 50 + '\n')
    print('The highest total score amongst the contestants is {:.2f}'.format(max(total_score)))
    print('The lowest total score amongst the contestants is {:.2f}'.format(min(total_score)))
```

---

**Output:**

```
The number of contestants is 5.
__________________________________________________
Contestent                       Scores
__________________________________________________
Albert          9.2  9.3  9.5  9.5  9.6  9.8
John            9.4  9.6  9.8  9.4  9.3  9.1
Jay             9.2  9.3  9.4  9.3  9.9  9.1
Henry           9.4  9.3  9.5  9.5  9.6  9.8
Walter          9.2  9.3  9.4  9.3  9.1  9.6
__________________________________________________
__________________________________________________

Total Score of Albert is:      9.48
Total Score of John is:        9.43
Total Score of Jay is:         9.37
Total Score of Henry is:       9.52
Total Score of Walter is:      9.32
__________________________________________________
__________________________________________________

The highest total score amongst the contestants is 9.52
The lowest total score amongst the contestants is 9.32
```

---

References:

1. with
2. format
3. list comprehension
4. min, max

Answer (score 0):

With pandas it could be done like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv('gym.txt', sep=' ', header=None).set_index(0)
df=df.where(df.values != df.min(axis=1)[:,None])
df=df.where(df.values != df.max(axis=1)[:,None])
df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
print('Contestant             Scores')
print('----------------------------------------')
print(df.to_string())
print('----------------------------------------')
print('''The highest total score amongst the contestants is {:.2f} achieved by {}
The lowest total score amongst the contestants is {:.2f} achieved by {}'''\
.format(max(df['mean']),np.argmax(df['mean']),min(df['mean']),np.argmin(df['mean'])))

Out:'''
Contestant             Scores
----------------------------------------
          1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8      mean
0                                                       
Albert  9.2  9.3  NaN  NaN  9.5  9.5  9.6  9.8  9.483333
John    NaN  9.4  9.6  9.8  9.4  9.3  NaN  NaN  9.500000
Jay     9.2  9.3  NaN  NaN  9.4  9.3  NaN  9.1  9.260000
Henry   9.4  9.3  NaN  NaN  9.5  9.5  9.6  9.8  9.516667
Walter  9.2  9.3  9.4  9.3  NaN  9.1  9.6  NaN  9.316667
----------------------------------------
The highest total score amongst the contestants is 9.52 achieved by Henry
The lowest total score amongst the contestants is 9.26 achieved by Jay'''
```

Comment: If you don't want to show the NaN that can be done as well, but I wanted to show where the min and max got dropped.